# How to delete some characters from a string by matching certain character in python

Tags: python

i am trying to delete certain portion of a string if a match found in the string as below

```
string = 'Newyork, NY'
```

I want to delete all the characters after the comma from the string including `comma`, if comma is present in the string

Can anyone let me now how to do this .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
string = string.split(',', 1)[0]
```

We split the string on the comma *once*, to save python the work of splitting on more commas.

Alternatively, you can use [`.partition()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
string = string.partition(',')[0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> 'Newyork, NY'.split(',', 1)[0]
'Newyork'
>>> 'Newyork, NY'.partition(',')[0]
'Newyork'
```

`.partition()` is the faster method:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("'one, two'.split(',', 1)[0]")
0.52929401397705078
>>> timeit.timeit("'one, two'.partition(',')[0]")
0.26499605178833008
```

Comment: For die hard regex uses - you may as well throw in `re.match('(.*?),', s).group(1)` - but yeah, definitely `str.split` with max_splits is the way to go

Comment: @jamylak: Indeed, and it is faster too.

Answer (score 1):

You can [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string with the delimiter `","`:

```
string.split(",")[0]
```

Example:

```
'Newyork, NY'.split(",") # ['Newyork', ' NY']
'Newyork, NY'.split(",")[0] # 'Newyork'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
s = "this, is"
m = s.index(',')
l = s[:m]
```

Answer (score 0):

A fwe options:

- `string[:string.index(",")]`

  This will raise a `ValueError` if `,` cannot be found in the string. Here, we find the position of the character with `.index` then use slicing.
- `string.split(",")[0]`

  The `split` function will give you a list of the substrings that were separated by `,`, and you just take the first element of the list. This will work even if `,` is not present in the string (as there'd be nothing to split in that case, we'd have `string.split(...) == [string]`)